# Avoid message "-​- Loading resources from .sqliterc"

Tags: sqlite

Minor problem, nevertheless irritating : Is there a way to avoid the following message from appearing each time I make a query :

> -- Loading resources from /Users/ThG/.sqliterc

Answer (score 12):

As a stupid workaround, this works:

```
<. sqlite your_sqlite.db 'select * from your_table'
```

This is because the [current code](https://github.com/mackyle/sqlite/blob/master/src/shell.c.in#L8276) does this:

```
 if( stdin_is_interactive ){
   utf8_printf(stderr,"-- Loading resources from %s\n",sqliterc);
 }
```

Forcing a stdin redirect thwarts this due to [this piece of code](https://github.com/mackyle/sqlite/blob/master/src/shell.c.in#L8440):

```
stdin_is_interactive = isatty(0);
```

This works as well:

```
sqlite -batch your_sqlite.db 'select * from your_table'
```

due to [this piece of code](https://github.com/mackyle/sqlite/blob/master/src/shell.c.in#L8555):

```
}else if( strcmp(z,"-batch")==0 ){
  /* Need to check for batch mode here to so we can avoid printing
  ** informational messages (like from process_sqliterc) before
  ** we do the actual processing of arguments later in a second pass.
  */
  stdin_is_interactive = 0;
}
```

but it's longer, so kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Unlike some *other* answers, this not only solves the problem, but respects the fact that some of us do like to have an `.sqliterc` for a reason, instead of assuming "bah who works in a shell anyway"

Answer (score 3):

I know that this question is PRETTY old now, but simply deleting '/Users/ThG/.sqliterc' should solve the problem.  '.sqliterc' is a configuration file for sqlite's interactive command line front-end.  If you don't spend a lot of time in there, you won't miss the file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In fact, I use the command line front-end. I suppose this means I shall have to put up with it...

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but @levant pied almost had the solution, you need to pass an additional -interactive to silence the --loading resources from.

```
$ sqlite3 -batch -interactive
SQLite version 3.31.1 2020-01-27 19:55:54
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .q
```

**EDIT January 2024

Another way to silence the loading message is to:

```
$ sqlite3 2>/dev/null
SQLite version 3.44.2 2023-11-24 11:41:44
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite>
```

Comment: Tried this and it works nicely executing from a script.

Answer (score 2):

That resource msg comes out on stderr, and it's followed by a blank line, so you could get rid of it with something like this (wrapped up in a script file of its own):

```
#!/bin/bash
sqlite3 -init /your/init/file /your/sqlite3/file.db "
    your
    SQL
    cmds
" 2>/dev/null | sed -e1d
```

Answer (score 2):

When using sqlite in shell scripts, you usually don't even want your `~/.sqliterc` to be loaded at all. This works well for me:

```bash
sqlite3 -init <(echo)
```

Explanation:

- `-init` specifies the file to load instead of `~/.sqliterc`.
- `<(echo)` uses [Process Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) to provide a path to a temporary empty file.

Comment: This does not work, now I see a `-- Loading resources from /dev/fd/63`.

Comment: @user1461607 And /dev/fd/63 is empty, so your ~/.sqliterc is not loaded.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Is there a reason to prefer the Process Substitution over simply `-init /dev/null` ?

Comment: @xyz no, no particular reason. I didn't try `/dev/null`. If it works as well, that's an even simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply rename your config file to disable the warning. And revert the rename to keep the configuration after use.

I use the following:

```sh
#suppress default configuration warnings
mv $HOME/.sqliterc $HOME/.backup.sqliterc 

# sqlite3 scripts...

#revert
mv $HOME/.backup.sqliterc $HOME/.sqliterc
```

Comment: Tried and this works nicely. However - and please don't be offended - the `-batch - interactive` answer seems more elegant.

Comment: Me? Offended? Yes, definitely  don't worry about that :)) You shall use whichever answer fulfills your purpose ‍♂️