# convert sprintf() statement to printf() statement in awk

Tags: awk, printf

i have a script in awk that executes a command via `sprintf()`.  this gives a return value.  i do not want any return values, i just want to execute the command.  i thought `printf()` would be a simple drop-in replacement, since the docs say the only difference between the two is the return value.  first, here's the lines from the script:

```bash
TICKCOUNT = 0
commandSQL = "sqlite3 -noheader -separator \" \" " db " \" %s \""
querySQL = "update pulseCount set pulses=" TICKCOUNT ";"
system(printf(commandSQL, querySQL))
```

when i run the script above, i get `-- Loading resources from /path/to/.sqliterc` as a return value.  i want to reduce the I/O as much as possible on this embedded device, so i don't want the extra cycles to give me feedback.  when i replace the `sprintf()` with `printf()`, i get this error: `awk: myScript.awk:4: Unexpected token`.

can someone explain why the disjunct given they're supposed to basically be the same command with the same syntax?  and what would i replace `sprintf()` with so as to reduce the I/O?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "reduce the I/O".  The difference between `printf` and `sprintf` is that `printf` prints to your terminal, and `sprintf` returns the result as a string.  You CLEARLY want `sprintf` here.  Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: What version of `awk` are you using?

Comment: Regarding "i don't want the extra cycles" - then don't use awk as if it were a shell. Every time you call `system()` you're forcing awk to spawn a shell to execute whatever command you give as `system()s` argument. That's an extremely slow, resource-heavy operation.

Comment: `sprintf()` has zero impact on I/O as it doesn't product any output, it just returns a string. `printf` impacts I/O as it prints output to stdout.

Comment: `-- Loading resources from /path/to/.sqliterc` is NOT a return value from that awk script (using `sprintf()` as `printf` won't work). It may well be output from `sqlite3`, I don't know, but if it is then you'd need to investigate how to get `sqlite3` to stop producing output. That'll be a tiny drop in the ocean compared to the remaining overhead of spawning a subshell to call `sqlite3` though.

Comment: @EdMorton   '...overhead pawning a subshell to call sqlite3'... i was just dumping to a text file, but we needed a timestamp and this embedded device only has `awk`, not `gawk` so it was the only way to get millisecond interval times.  what would be faster?  i literally do not know.

Comment: i'm using awk because the guy before me used it.  it's a gong show of code/system conflicts.  and management is... well. management.  i am a network guy who's drafted to write code cuz i'm the only one that CAN.  so i am open to all suggestions for a faster way to execute a bash command every 10ms and write the results with a timecode to be harvested my a parent python application.

Comment: Your code is going to execute `sqlite3 foo` in a subshell, not print `sqlite3 foo` to a text file. Which do you actually want to happen - the command `sqlite3 foo` to be executed or the string `sqlite3 foo` to be written to a file?

Comment: @WhiteRau : why not just change last line to just `printf(commandSQL, querySQL)` - then you'll eliminate the sub-shell, get that `printf` you desire, while performing the same functionality

Comment: that said, i'd rephrase your `commandSQL` and `querySQL` to fit the syntax of `printf()` - namely - move `db` and `TICKCOUNT` to the back as arguments, and merging the remaining 2 strings as the formatter for `printf()`, something like `printf("sqlite3 -noheader -separator \42 \42 \42%s\42 querySQL = \42update pulseCount set pulses=%s\42;", db, TICKCOUNT)` ? (not too familiar with sqlite3 syntax)

Comment: i tried replacing it with `printf` but got an `unexpected token` error.  O_o  which is weird because they're basically the same command..... aren't they??  ah.  apparently not.  ok.

Comment: `printf()` is a statement so you can't wrap it inside another function, namely, `system(…)`

Comment: No, as described in previous comments, they are not basically the same command. If they were then we wouldn't need 2 of them. What they have in common is that they create a string from a format string and some data values, but aside from that they are quite different.

Comment: gotcha.  thanks guys.  this is new territory for me, obviously.  presuming \42 is the escaped quotes?  it give me an `unexpected token` error.

Comment: I may see a clue to what you're trying to do in [an earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78189297/convert-sprintf-statement-to-printf-statement-in-awk?noredirect=1#comment137845716_78189297). I THINK what you might actually be trying to do is execute that sqlite3 command to get a timestamp to output to give timing about some other command. But then you also said "to be harvested my a parent python application" - if you have python sitting above all this, why not just use that directly instead of calling python to call awk to call shell to call sqlite3?

Comment: @EdMorton  because python cannot run the necessary bash command that samples the datapool fast enough to get a 10-15ms sampling rate on the device; it has ONE core available to us to use.  the other core is locked, providing a datapool of port information.  the only way we can hit that interval target is by running it outside the interpreter and checking the count totals every couple of seconds.  the count has to be accurate, but the reporting is much looser, time-wise.  nightmare.  the only reason we're entertaining this is the platform is a compact system.

Comment: that replaces a PLC, MQTT broker, GSM, GPS, router, and sensor platform.  i'm pushing this thing to it's limits as best i know how, but this is outside my baliwick in terms of squeezing max performance while reducing as much I/O on the ONE CORE as possible.  just kill me now.  :P

Comment: If python using it's internal timing primitives can't do it fast enough then python or shell calling awk calling shell calling sqlite3 definitely can't do it fast enough.

Comment: I feel like if you provided a [mcve] showing what you're really trying to do with this code then we may be able to help you but I don't even know if this is being called from a python script or a separate process (and if so why do we care that there's some other python script) or what your sql command does and why you're doing it, etc. And I don't know what we should be able to determine about this problem from that list of acronyms, though I suspect it's all irrelevant.

Comment: Anyway, getting back to your actual question, use `sprintf()` as you presumably had been using and see https://stackoverflow.com/q/4174897/1745001 for various ways to get `sqlite3` to stop printing that output you don't want (to me, [`sqlite3 -batch -interactive`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60033386/1745001) looks most likely to be the right approach but idk - lots to choose from on that question and the `sqlite3` man page). Ask a new question with a [mcve] if you'd like help beyond that.

Comment: @EdMorton   here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78190193/best-method-to-improve-awk-speed-in-writing-to-sqlite3-db