# best method to improve awk speed in writing to sqlite3 db

Tags: python, bash, awk

i have a device that runs BusyBox, has ONE processor available for client use, and needs to run as a flow pulse counter (among other things), catching zero or many pulses of 20ms in width at random intervals within each second.

the device has a second processor walled off from the client dedicated to creating a muxed datapool of it's I/O port signals.  the muxed signal is available via a manufacturer provided awk script, which i have modified to provide a TICKCOUNT that increments when the demuxed signal reports '1'.  i can't share the manufacturer's code, obviously, but i can share mine.

alongside of this runs a python application that collects signal data from the mux stream and reports it via MQTT to an Ignition dashboard for client consumption/management/whatever.  the MQTT reporting interval is 5sec.  the pulse count check against the store value (text file/sqlite db) is every 2sec, enabling plenty of time to perform a flow rate calculation and report it back via MQTT to the consuming dashboard.

in order to be able to capture the pulse signal, i had to get sampling rate below 15ms.  running the awk script balls out in an eternal `while` loop did the trick; i'm able to consistenly get ~7-11ms read intervals.  and i *was* just outputting to a text file so python could read from THAT and do what it wanted with it, using the MQTT timestamp to calculate flow rates.

enter management.  flow rate calculations must now be done on the device, not on the dashboard server.  wth.

so now Read/Write times matter a hell of a lot more and i've switched the script to writing to an sqlite database to get a rolling timestamp on the writes that python can then access and pass on via MQTT.

my issue is, the count appears to no longer be accurate because the Read from the database in python's subshell PLUS the subshell required to excute the sqlite3 query in awk are interrupting the sampling speed.  if this had another core to dump the sampling to, this would be a non-issue.

so.  how can i best optimize this awk code for as much speed as possible to claw back as many cycles as possible to retain coherence with actual pulse counts?  and i'm fully willing to accept this is no longer doable.

the awk code (from memory because i'm not currently sitting at the device):

```bash
#!/bin/awk -f
# proprietary code that sets the mux config
BEGIN {
  TICKCOUNT = 0
  db = "path/to/pulseCount.db"
  commandSQL = "sqlite3 -noheader " db " \"%s\";"

  while(1) {
    # more proprietary code that reads the mux and dumps value to DIN variable
    if (DIN == '1') {
      TICKCOUNT++
      querySQL = "update pulseCount set pulses=" TICKCOUNT ";"
      system(sprintf(commandSQL, querySQL))
    }
  }
}
END {
}
```

this works; dumping a crapton of return values into `stdout` from the `sqlite3` call, but i'm told this isn't a performance concern.  (plus, as i think about it, when running in production, nohup will dump it to /dev/null anyway).  HOWEVER, i'm told the overhead of opening `system()` is killing speed faster than PolPot 'cleansing' West Timor in the 90's.  that's bad.

i'm not sure where to optimize from here.  i am historically an InfoSec/Network guy coming out of WebDev.  i'm not hardware experienced.  so, go gently.  i am open to any advice on how to beat this thing and, if it can't be done, i am open to that option as well; in which case i'll find some other way to get done what needs doing.

thank you for your patience.  this is a long one.

Comment: Easy answer is to pipe awk's output into sqlite rather than having it _start_ sqlite at all. awk's `system()` is generally a mess -- interfaces that don't let you pass an explicit argv array are best avoided in the first place, since passing a shell a string that commingles code and data is a fast route to injection attacks. (Granted, not such an issue _here_, since you aren't accepting the `db` parameter from an untrusted source, but true as a matter of general principle).

Comment: That said, I'm surprised that you're better off running an external copy of awk piping to sqlite rather than a separate Python process using sqlite through the relevant module -- using a prepared statement is generally going to be more efficient than any interface that requires starting the parsing from the beginning for every piece of input, and prepared statements _require_ a level of integration you can't get with the command line tool and stdin.

Comment: Anyhow, bottom line, if you really want the fastest possible way to run a bunch of tiny sqlite statements quickly, I'd probably use an entirely different stack -- most likely Go. The Python interpreter has overhead, parsing SQL queries as strings has overhead; if you really want to optimize for spending as much time as possible in sqlite itself and as little in anything else, neither Python _nor_ awk _nor_ the command-line sqlite client is ideal.

Comment: (The other advantage of Go in this context is that it builds static executables; as long as you compile your code without CGo, you'll have no problem targeting an embedded device even if it doesn't use glibc; see https://github.com/glebarez/go-sqlite for a pure-Go sqlite library that doesn't require CGo)

Comment: ++ on the idea of using something other than `awk` ... connect/disconnect with db each time is expensive, parse-n-compile of each `update` is expensive; having said that, if you really, Really, REALLY have to continue using `awk` then consider coprocesses (open/maintain connection to db, pump `update` statements into the coprocess/pipe); web search on `awk coprocess` should bring up a good number of hits (hits on `www.gnu.org/s/gawk` are a good start)

Comment: as already mentioned ... open a connection to the database once and then keep open (plus code to (re)connect if you get disconnected - which hopefully isn't very often); minimize the number of times you need to parse-n-compile the `update` (prepared statements==great; stored proc==good)

Comment: steamlining the `awk` script ... combine `commandSQL` and `querySQL` into a single static variable (defined before the `while(1)` loop) with a single placeholder `%s`; then replace the current `if (DIN==1)` block with `if (DIN==1) system(sprintf(command_query_SQL,++TICKCOUNT))`; every statement in the `awk` script does take up some small slice of time (though not as heavy a cost as the `system()` call) so eliminating unnecessary statements should add a small improvement

Comment: You could save a cycle if you don't call `sprintf()`, just concatenate the strings `commandSQL = "sqlite3 -noheader " db " \""; ... system(command_query_SQL (++TICKCOUNT) "\";")` but I highly doubt you'll ever get the performance you need out of using awk + subshells like this. We know you have python so if you can't use `Go` as @CharlesDuffy suggested then do this timing process in `python`. It's not obvious why you don't have the main `python` process just do this part for itself too (though "the muxed signal is available via a manufacturer provided awk script" may be a clue!).

Comment: i tried running a Python thread to sample the I/O, but i couldn't get the speed needed to accurately capture the 10ms pulse spike.  after a long night of reading specs, i'm beginning to wonder if the processor thread just can't handle the saturation necessary to capture accurately AND run the application.  there's also the possibility i may not be a good enough programmer at this point to make it happen... :\  the biggest irritation is all the utilities necessary to gather signals is written by the manufacturer in awk.  i'm sure i could translate most of them to Python, but the speed

Comment: just isn't there, AFAIK.  the Python interpreter just isn't fast enough on this hardware.  so i'm going to try the suggestions made and give it another shot today.  thanks everyone.

Comment: following you suggestion, @EdMorton, i concatenated down but when i run it, i get an `Unterminated quoted string` error.  here's the snippet: `commandSQL = "sqlite3 -noheader -separator \" \" " /path/to/db " \"update pulseCount set pulses=\""
    if (DIN1 == "1") system(commandSQL ++TICKCOUNT "\";")`

Comment: disregard.  i forgot to remove a set of quotes.  \*facepalm\*

Comment: You also forgot the parens around `++TICKCOUNT`. When you write `foo ++bar`, it's syntactically the same as writing `foo ++ bar` or `foo++ bar` so if you want to ensure that awk treats the `++` as a pre-increment of `bar`, i.e. `foo (++bar)`, then that's what you need to write. Awk will TRY to figure out what you meant by the types of `foo` and `bar` but just write what you mean for robustness and clarity.

Comment: I'd say if you're stuck using shell to call awk to call shell to call sqlite3 then get rid of the "to call awk to call shell" part and just call  `sqlite3` directly from the shell script that's currently calling awk , but whether that's reasonable or not depends on what "# more proprietary code that reads the mux and dumps value to DIN variable" is doing and whether or not that could be implemented differently if necessary.

Comment: well.  goalposts just got moved at lunch.  this is no longer an issue because they've decided to go ModbusRTU instead.  FFS.  welcome to my life.  at least i learned a TON from all your help and i'm very, very grateful.  salty, (not at you guys) but grateful.